# Insert today's date with button, as date, not function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I use this VBA:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

But the value of the cell becomes `=NOW()`, not the date.

I want to push the button and get *2015-03-13*, and when I open the sheet tomorrow, it should still say *2015-03-13*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
ActiveCell.Value=Now
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should consider:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl+: appears to insert the time. Ctrl+; appears to insert the date.

Answer (score 0):

Your code ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
is absolutely perfect. It works correctly on my System. You not need to till
tomorrow to check the output of this code, first write this code and run macro and save and close it (please check the date). After closing the file change your system date i.e suppose today is 13-Mar then set the 14-Mar date of your system timing then open the file , you will observer the date in is change.
you can write this Thisworkbook in open workbook event.

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveCell.Value = Now
End Sub

Comment: Please think on two different line ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()" and ActiveCell.Value = Now  for first line you need not run macro every time to change the date in case 2nd line you need to run the macro every time.