# How to freeze the =today() function once data has been entered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to use the =TODAY() function in a table in excel. However, once data has been entered into that table row, I would like it never to change dates again (effectively capturing the date the row's data was added).

This will be used on every row in the table, so as data is entered into the table down the rows, each date will be captured.

Is this possible, how do I do it?

EDIT - pnuts it is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032063/insert-todays-date-with-button-as-date-not-function) question. I do not want to use a button, rather a cell formula.

Comment: The [TODAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566) is volatile and recalculates on every calculation cycle in the workbook. If you want a **timestamp** look towards a VBA **Worksheet_Change** event macro that automatically puts a static Date or Now into a column when data in that row has been appended or edited. There are many examples on this site. Search the Excel forum for [timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5Dworksheet_change+timestamp). Post back if you run into trouble (include your own effort).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Rather than entering the formula

```
=TODAY()
```

touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

instead.  This will put a "frozen" date in the cell.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that particular shortcut. Thanks for pointing it out. Experimenting with it, I discovered that `Ctrl+Shift+;` gives you a frozen time, which is also nice.

Comment: is there any shortcut for adding both i.e. date + time?

Comment: @ninbit not a single shortcut

Comment: @ninbit (I use to do it... , when I need the text) but not in excel. --> Press F5 in notepad. | As for excel, the formula is `now()`. Afaik, no kbd shortcut.

Comment: @ninbit Pressing `Ctrl` + `;`, then `Space`, then `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `;` seems to work.

Answer (score 7):

Gary's Student answer is best for this specific problem, but it is possible to freeze volatile worksheet functions without VBA if you are willing to use circular references. In `File\Options\Formulas` check `Enable iterative calculation` Then, assuming that A1 is currently blank, enter

```
=IF(A1 = 0,TODAY(),A1)
```

Excel's default format handling doesn't know to format this as date - so you would need to do this separately. More work than `Ctrl + ;`, but there might be some other use-cases of this trick.

Disclaimer: I explicitly tested that this trick prevents recalculation of `Now()` rather than `Today()`. I wasn't willing to wait until midnight to test `Today()`.

On edit: Here is an interesting use-case. Say you have an entire range of blank cells with A1 as the upper left corner cell. While that range is highlighted, enter the formula

```
=IF(A1 = 0, RAND(), A1)
```

and hit `Ctrl + Enter`. Then the entire range fills up with different but fixed random values.

Comment: Instead of checking the value of A1, the condition can simply be TRUE: `IF(TRUE,TODAY(),0)`.

Comment: @Valid No it cannot, true is always true, so you would evaluate the `TODAY()` function every time. Thus, its value would not be fixed to the day you set it up.