# Making a Date formula not update

Tags: google-sheets

I'm Making a formula that creates and automatic date to the current day by using the "If" formula and "today/now" formula. Iv managed to make this happen, but it keeps on updating every single day. is there any other approach to this.

```
=if(F6="Bronze",NOW(),if(F6="Silver",NOW(),if(F6="Gold",NOW())))
```

I will love to know whats the right syntax for that kind of operation?

**Iv seen other answer, but they don't solve the issue for my needs**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to freeze the =today() function once data has been entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771194/how-to-freeze-the-today-function-once-data-has-been-entered)

Comment: Hey @tom,
Its not quite the same answer, it helped.
In my situation i'm automating the DATE input via " if " Statement and not manually. So every time I click enter a specific value today's date will appear. so the answer just helps for manual input. thanks :)