# Excel date formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am really struggling with excel, if this is easy then I apologize, but I'm very new to using excel so clear instructions would be really helpful.

The task I'm trying to achieve is creating a spreadsheet to track the dates of some safety checks on equipment.
I have columns for the equipment name (which doesn't change), and the name of the person who checked it, which needs to be filled manually, I am trying to use a formula to automatically input the date of check (the current date) and the date the next check is needed (3, 6, or 12 months from the current date depending on the piece of equipment in question). I have tried using the TODAY() function, and TODAY()+X(number of days), but these change every day which is not what I want, is there any way to have excel automatically calculate and fill these dates, but then not change them until a particular cell (i.e. name of person who checked) is updated?

I know about setting calculation to manual, but that stops calculations even when new data is entered, I need to be able to update the sheet, and have existing dates remain unchanged (hoping that makes sense).

And again, very new to excel, so please make answers as easy to follow as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, all the best.

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771194/how-to-freeze-the-today-function-once-data-has-been-entered

Comment: There's also this, although you might feel it is too ambitious at this stage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Answer (score 1):

### Simplest solution (that works on all machines):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771724/7602468

### Official OEM solution :

Use `Worksheet.Change` event in your VBA code.

ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Credit :

- @Euler's Disgraced Stepchild
- @Tom Sharpe
- @Gary's Student

<sub>Please share if it works/not..</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://trumpexcel.com/date-timestamp-excel/#Creating-a-Custom-Function-to-Insert-Timestamp) is a page that can help. Scroll to

> Creating a Custom Function to Insert Timestamp