# Freeze and and Track Dates in Excel

Tags: excel, date, drop-down-menu

I am trying to track when shipments arrive and leave a warehouse. Along with this I am trying to calculate the time spent in the warehouse.

The ideal solution would include a function where I would select which warehouse the shipment is arriving in and in a separate cell in the workbook it gives back the current date. At a later date I state that the item has left the warehouse, likely through use of a "yes' or "No" drop down menu, and another cell freezes the date of the day that it left. The purpose is to track how long a shipment stays in storage.

I realize I could go through and simply click CTRL+; but there are tens of thousands of shipments to track so it's unreasonable to do so.

This is the current function I have

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(N9)),"",DATEDIF(M9,TODAY(),"D"))
```

This is a circular function but if you click on the link below it explains why it works

I got it from this thread: [How to freeze the =today() function once data has been entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771194/how-to-freeze-the-today-function-once-data-has-been-entered)

What I need to add is the piece where it interacts with the drop down menus.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Circular Functions are very finicky and require the change to the options in Excel as a whole.  VBA in a worksheet_change event is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks, I've never used VBA, I'll lookup a tutorial.

Comment: Hello, I have looked up tutorials and such and understand how macros work and how to make them. However I don't see a way to automate them? How can I get a macro to run without me having to use a shortcut or go into the Macros list and running it? Is there a command for that or do they only run when a person tells it to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change